# Best way to display an entire chapter of formatted text

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Seeking feedback on best to approach this:

I am building a study guide BBapp.  So there will be Subject > Topic/Chapter > Contents.

For contents, it will be a lot of formatted text and possibly a few images.  The formatting will be on section headings, key points, etc.

**Which is better suited for an entire chapter of text - RichTextField or BrowserField?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking about Browserfield.
That way it will be easier to make links to anchor on same chapter or another.
You can also create foward and backward buttons to navigate.

And also you can look at the files in a computer or send them by mail easily.